# Determine which binary will run via execlp in advance

Tags: c, linux, exec, system-calls, execl

## Edit #1

---

The "Possible duplicates" so far are **not** duplicates. They test for the existence of `$FILE` in `$PATH`, rather than providing the full path to the first valid result; and the top answer uses [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) command line commands, not pure [c](/questions/tagged/c).

## Original Question

---

Of all the exec family functions, there are a few which do `$PATH` lookups rather than requiring an absolute path to the binary to execute.

**From `man exec`**:

> The execlp(), execvp(), and execvpe() functions duplicate the actions
>   of the shell in searching for an executable file if the specified
>   filename does not  contain  a  slash
>          (/)  character.  The file is sought in the colon-separated list of directory pathnames specified in the PATH environment variable.  If
>   this variable isn't defined, the path
>          list defaults to the current directory  followed  by  the  list  of  directories  returned  by  confstr(_CS_PATH).   (This  confstr(3) 
>   call  typically  returns  the  value
>          "/bin:/usr/bin".)

Is there a simple, straightforward way, to test what the first "full path to execute" will evaluate to, without having to manually iterate through all the elements in the `$PATH` environment variable, and appending the binary name to the end of the path? I would like to use a "de facto standard" approach to estimating the binary to be run, rather than re-writing a task that has likely already been implemented several times over in the past.

I realize that this won't be a guarantee, since someone could potentially invalidate this check via a buggy script, TOCTOU attacks, etc. I just need a decent approximation for testing purposes.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C, runtime test if executable exists in PATH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035372/c-runtime-test-if-executable-exists-in-path)

Comment: Why do you ask? What is the actual use case? Please **edit your question** to motivate it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I wish to know what program will (likely) be executed in advance for testing purposes.

Comment: The tests a security-sensitive application should (in my paranoid opinion) do, is first locate the actual binary to be executed (and later use the exact full path), and check the ownership of the file, directory, and all parent directories, twice. The idea is to verify that no untrusted user has write access to any of them; the second pass is to verify that nothing changed from the first pass (bait-and-switch). UID 0, GID 0 ("root") is always trusted, any other trusted accounts depend on the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a simple, straightforward way, to test what the first "full path to execute" will evaluate to, without having to manually iterate through all the elements in the $PATH environment variable

No, you need to iterate thru `$PATH` (i.e. `getenv("PATH")` in C code). Some (non standard) libraries provide a way to do that, but it is really so simple that you should not bother. You could use [strchr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html) to find the "next" occurrence of colon `:`, so coding that loop is really simple. As [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) commented, they are subtleties (e.g. permissions, hanging symbolic links, some *other* process adding some new executable to a directory mentionned in your `$PATH`) but most programs ignore them.

And what is really relevant is the `PATH` value before running `execvp`. In practice, it is the value of `PATH` when starting your program (because outside processes cannot change it). You just need to be sure that your program don't change `PATH` which is very likely (the corner case, and difficult one, would be some other thread -of the same [*process*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29)- changing the `PATH` environment variable with [putenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/putenv.3.html) or [setenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setenv.3.html)).

In *practice* the `PATH` won't change (unless *you* have some code explicitly changing it). Even if you use proprietary libraries and don't have time to check their source code, you can expect `PATH` to stay the same in practice during execution of your process.

If you need some more precise thing, and assuming you use `execp` functions on program names which are compile time constants, or at least constant after your program initialization reading some configuration files, you could do what many shells are doing: "caching" the result of searching the `PATH` into some hash table, and using `execve` on that. Still, you cannot avoid the issue of some *other* process adding or removing files into directories mentioned in your `PATH`; but most programs don't care (and are written with the implicit hypothesis that this don't happen, or is notified to your program: look at the `rehash` builtin of `zsh` as an example).

But you *always* need to test against failure of `exec` (including [execlp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) & [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)) and `fork` functions. They could fail for many reasons, even if the `PATH` has not changed and directories and files mentioned in it have not been changed.

Comment: There are tricky bits to parsing a PATH value.  Formally, if the first character is a colon, or the last character is a colon, or there are two adjacent colons in the PATH, then the directory name is (implicitly) '`.`' (dot, the current directory).  There are other complicating factors too: checking the permissions on the file, ACLs (which might hide that a user or group has permission when in fact they do), maybe checking permissions on the directory, though if you can check permissions on the file, you're usually OK.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: in principle you are perfectly right. In practice, one often don't care.

Comment: Thank you. This is far more informative than the "possible duplicate" linked to this question.